# In BeautifulSoup how do you access the tag's str that is equal to the class name?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi guys I was wondering if it is possible to access the str equal to the class name, what I mean by this is shown in the example below:

```
<tr data-username="g964">lol</tr>
```

I don't want to access the text that  contains but instead access the text/string that the class name `data-username` contains, basically is it possible to access the `"g964"`? I'm asking this because let's imagine a loop that goes to all of the `<tr></tr>` and retrieves the `data-username` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the property you should do like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<tr data-username="g964">lol1</tr>
<tr data-username="g964">lol2</tr>
<tr data-username="g964">lol3</tr>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all('tr'):
    print(item.get('data-username'))
```

you can change 'data-username' with any property you want to access of a tag, like, class, id....

this is the output:

```
g964
g964
g964
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<tr data-username="g964">lol1</tr>
<tr data-username="g964">lol2</tr>
<tr data-username="g964">lol3</tr>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all('tr',attrs={"data-username":"g964"}):
    print(item.text)
```

Or you can use following css selector.

```
for item in soup.select('tr[data-username="g964"]'):
    print(item.text)
```

---

To get `data-username` value try this.

```
html='''<tr data-username="g964">lol1</tr>
<tr data-username="g964">lol2</tr>
<tr data-username="g964">lol3</tr>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all('tr',attrs={"data-username":True}):
    print(item['data-username'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to extract the different class values data-username has.
You can pass BeautifulSoup4's (since BS 4.1.2, to be precise) `class_` a string, regex, function or `True`. This is the same as any keyword argument.

For example, if you wanted the one or more you can pass it something like this regex:
`soup.find_all(class_=".+")` or be super greedy for username classes with `soup.find_all("tr data-username", class_=".*")`.

If you don't have the latest version of BS, you can pass a dict like object to the keyword `attrs` to find class values. I'm 99% sure this was a workaround, so using BS4.1.2< is best. There are some explanations and simple examples in the Docs on www.crummy.com.